# How to check whether conditions holds before displaying resultset values in java

Tags: java

I have a method which retrieved values from resultset where some column values is 1.

Now I want  to apply a condition which states that when `beam_current = 101.20` ,`beam_energy=2500.063` and `st1_prmt_status_p45=1` then the values should be printed.

My code for displaying values is:

```
public LinkedHashMap < String, Integer > beam_CurrentStatus() throws SQLException {

  try

  {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    while (rs.next()) {

      for (int j = 2; j < 29; j++) {
        if (rs.getInt(j) == 1) {

          String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
          map.put(name, rs.getInt(j));

        }
      }
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " + e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }
  return map;
}
```

I want to apply the condition like

```
if(rs.getInt(29)==1|| rs.getDouble(30)==101.20||rs.getDouble(30)==2500.063)
        {

for (int j = 2; j < 29; j++)
            {.......
```

But this if condition has no effect on for loop??How to apply this if condition in while loop??

Comment: The code you are showing is for storing results into a `map`.

Comment: @PM77-1 The stored value is being displayed.I want to store only those values which satisfies the above mentioned condition.

Comment: Your conditions are spelled out with `and` but programmed with `||` (or). Is it intentional?

Answer (score 3):

I think in below condition is wrong :

```
if(rs.getInt(29)==1|| rs.getDouble(30)==101.20||rs.getDouble(30)==2500.063)
```

Below is your condition :

```
st1_prmt_status_p45=1
beam_current = 101.20 
beam_energy=2500.063
```

This should be condition :

```
if(rs.getInt(29)==1|| rs.getDouble(30)==101.20||rs.getDouble(31)==2500.063)
```

**rs.getDouble(30) ===> rs.getDouble(31)**